# Can I serialize a BitArray to XML?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, bitarray

I have a business class which I need to serialize to xml. It has a BitArray property.

I have decorated it with `[XmlAttribute]` but the serialization is failing with

*To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add(System.Boolean) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. System.Collections.BitArray does not implement Add(System.Boolean).*

I am not sure whether its possible to serialize to xml?

If not what would be an efficient means of serializing the BitArray

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly serialize a BitArray to XML.  The reason is that in order to de-serialize it you'd need an Add method which BitArray doesn't supply.

You can, however, copy it to an array that can be serialized:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(128);
int[] baBits = new int[4];  // 4 ints makes up 128 bits

ba.CopyTo(baBits, 0);
// Now serialize the array
```

Going the other way involves deserializing the array and calling the BitArray constructor:

```
int[] baBits;  // This is deserialized somehow
BitArray ba = new BitArray(baBits);
```

If you do this, you'll want your BitArray size to be a multiple of the word size (i.e. if you use an array of int, then your BitArray size should be a multiple of 32).

Answer (score 0):

As something quick and dirty, how about create a property which has the [XmlAttribute], and it's getter return an array created from your BitArray by using the static BitArray.CopyTo method?