# Compress array of boolean arrays to send over the web

Tags: arrays, wcf, web-services, compression

I have a client application that creates an array of boolean arrays which I need to send to a WCF web service which I'll be creating. Do I need to compress the boolean arrays into something more compact like an array of Int32's or Int64's? Part of this question stems from my lack of understanding of WCF web services and whether or not they have the ability to accept more complex data types or not. When I think of web services, I get the feeling that they can only handle the same kind of data that one could store in a hidden form field on a web page. If that's the case, instead of passing a huge string of ones and zeros, I'd rather compress the data into something more compact like a string of integers or a string of 
ASCII characters. I hope I'm making sense. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compress the arrays, although it seems like a good idea. If you are using .NET throughout you should check out the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456713/can-i-serialize-a-bitarray-to-xml) may be helpful as well.